# Google Cloud Stackdriver Logging - Log Export to BigQuery - Access to the dataset was denied

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have created an export sink from Google Cloud - Stackdriver Logging to BigQuery. After the setup everything works fine for days or weeks.

Then suddenly I get the error message:

"Access to the dataset was denied
StackdriverLogsPARTITIONED/script_googleapis_com_console_logs$20191117"

and

"The specified dataset does not allow the service account associated with the log sink to write to it. Grant write permission for the service account specified in the sink's writerIdentity field on the dataset. Learn more"

I did not change the permissions for the service account nor did I change anything else within BigQuery.

What I have tried so far:

- I have tried to link the export to a BigQuery partitioned dataset and also to a "default" dataset.
- I have tried to give all permissions to the service account. So full access to the Google Cloud project, full access to BigQuery.
- I have also tried to create a new export sink and use the existing BigQuery dataset.

Nothing worked so far. The only approach that works is to create a new export sink and create a new BigQuery dataset. This is not very handy, because the number of BigQuery datasets are rising and the data is distributed to different datasets. I assume there is a way to merge these datasets, I would prefer a solution to avoid this error from happening.

Comment: I know you said you did not change service account permissions, but did you actually validate that the service account still has the right permissions?

Comment: Have you checked if the setup is still exporting even if the error is appearing or is the error blocking the logs from getting exported?

Comment: @YuriGrinshteyn Yes I have validated that the service account still has edit permissions.

Comment: @PhilippSh Unfortunately the error blocks the logs from getting exported.

Comment: I think you ought to submit a support case at this point, if you haven't already.

Comment: You should contact support in this case. In case you don’t have support  refer to the [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) and create an issue so that your issue can be tracked. You will find the steps to create an issue [here](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/create-issue-ui).

Comment: Was there any resolution for this? I am having the same issue and I think it is because the project does not have billing enabled. I am also unable to see the service account permissions so it would be great for some instructions on that. The SA that was created with the sink does not show up in the normal iam service account tab. I will explore my options with gcloud cli now. `gcloud iam  service-accounts list` does not show the google managed service accounts.

Comment: Unfortunately no solution yet. I have opened an issue, but did not get support: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154426878